# Xcode: Changing Base SDK from 12 to 12.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I just submitted a sticker app from Xcode and am getting this error:

> SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 12.0 SDK. Starting
>   March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with
>   the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later.

I'm using XCode 10.1, and I understand how to change the deployment target, but is that different than the Base SDK?

How do I change my Base SDK, and do I need to change my deployment target as well? (In my Project Settings, it's currently set at 10.3)

Comment: But, no, you don’t have to change your deployment target. Just the base SDK.

Comment: I validated settings, it didn't change anything. What else do I need to do to change the Base SDK, if anything?

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest validating your settings by selecting the top level project in the “Project Navigator” and then choose “Editor” » “Validate Settings...”. This can sometimes find and remedy outdated Base SDK settings:

[image: validate settings]

If that doesn’t do it, go to your “target settings”, select the target, and then explicitly set the “Base SDK”. In my case, in Xcode 10.1, choosing “iOS” automatically chooses the latest, iOS 12.1:

[image: base SDK]

But, no, “Base SDK” and “Deployment Target” are two different things. The “Deployment Target” is the minimum OS version that you plan on supporting. You should feel free to leave that set to 10.3, or whatever minimum OS version you plan on supporting.

---

Needless to say, if you have two versions of Xcode installed on your machine, make sure you’re firing up the latest version (Xcode 10.1 at this point). Sometimes if you just double-click on the project/workspace in Finder, it might not be starting up the version of Xcode you think it is.

Comment: Yes, I did both of those things: Validated settings, and checked the Base SDK and made sure it was choosing iOS. Still get the error though. I also have only one version of Xcode on my machine.

Comment: I should also add, I'm able to successfully build and submit my app, so I don't even know if this is a big deal, I just want to make sure it'll keep working in the future.